# FadeOut doesn't work with latest version of jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){$(".loading").fadeOut("slow");})
```

It works fine with jQuery 1.5.2, but not at all with jQuery 3.4.1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to listen for the `load` event

Binding directly to`load` was removed in jQuery 3.0, according to their [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> Note: This API has been removed in jQuery 3.0; please use .on( "load", handler ) instead of .load( handler ) and .trigger( "load" ) instead of .load().

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $(".loading").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="loading">Demo</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the fadeOut now works with the new jQuery. Unfortunately, now it is executing BEFORE the window/page has loaded instead of AFTER as it does with the earlier version of jQuery. Is there a "fix" for that also?

Comment: It should work the same, it's listening for the same Event - is it possible for to create a codepen / jsfiddle to show this problem?

Comment: I am new to this, so please excuse my ignorance of not knowing what a codepen is. I can share the rest of the code. It really is simple, it is on the homepage of a website that has a few graphics. The page should not be displayed until all the graphics have loaded. The old jQuery works fine, I was just trying to get all my jQuery scripts to run on the same version.

Comment: [JSFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) and [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) are both sites to build and share your code, with areas for HTML / CSS / HTML to make it easier; You would just copy paste your code onto those sites for me ( and others ) to see

Comment: I tried JSFiddle but couldn't recreate the problem. Maybe because my page is an .asp. Nevermind, I will leave it with jQuery 1.5.2 as it works fine.

Comment: I don't imagine your issue is with this function, it's the exact same thing they just changed the naming for the API - the load event is what you're listening for, and the load event is fired when *everything* on the page is loaded

Comment: All I know is that the following code works fine, but when I uncomment the "new" line and comment-out the old two lines, then it stops working.
`code`
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/alertbrowser.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/selectbuttons.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/preload.js"></script>
<!--<script>$(window).on("load", function(){$(".loading").fadeOut("slow");})</script>-->
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script>$(window).load(function(){$(".loading").fadeOut("slow");})</script>
</head>
<body onload="Redi...

Comment: I can't see the issue I'm afraid, assuming jQuery is loading - You can read more for upgrading from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15631837/11998782), if upgrading is something you actually want to do at this point